# Basic Auth Response for wrong User

Tags: php, authentication, basic-authentication

I do have a working PHP basic auth code for 1 user per domain.
**But I don't get it working with 2 different users on 1 domain in the same client** (calendars: thunderbird-lightning, mac calendar).

**Here is my example:**

```
$auth = null;
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    $auth = login($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'], 'basic');
    if ($auth->getUser() != $theCorrectUser) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"');
        header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8', true);
        http_response_code(403);
        echo 'wrong user';
        exit;
    }
}
if (!$auth) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"');
    header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8', true);
    http_response_code(401);
    echo 'invalid user';
    exit;
}
// still there? -> user is logged in and correct
```

**Example Links:**

- [www.test.com/user_a/calendar.ics](http://www.test.com/user_a/calendar.ics) -> User A only
- [www.test.com/user_b/calendar.ics](http://www.test.com/user_b/calendar.ics) -> User B only

**The idea:**

- if there is no Basic Auth or it's wrong -> HTTP Response 401
- if the Basic Auth is right, but the user has no access to the source -> HTTP Response 403

**The Problem:**

- when I send 403, the client will not ask the user to input another username+passwort
- if I would also send a 401 for wrong user attempts, the client will "logout" all users for this domain

*What's the trick having multiple basic-auth users at once in the same client? :)*

Comment: You should use different realms for parts of the site that have different access. So if the user isn't allowed to access this page, they won't be logged out of other pages in the domain.

Comment: I guess sessions would be easier for this kind of thing.

Comment: @JoelCrypto may you have an example for me? I do use sessions for the rest of the site, but I have no idea how to combine them with basic auth. Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar thanks. I tried sending another realm with 401 instead of 403 to force the user promt. but this didn't work.

Comment: Why you want to combine both? You can Connect using modals or forms, user friendly.

Comment: @JoelCrypto because the user doesn't log into my website, he logs into his calendar app. so I can't render an form for the user without the need of all the oAuth logic, can I?

Comment: Actually you can store a token that will allow connection and change it each Time. But Basically oauth seems more secure. But you can add session from a basic auth too.

Comment: @JoelCrypto well, may be. but how? ;) I'm not sure, if using sessions really solves the issue. The auth itself is not the problem, the client sends the user+passwort anyway. but the wrong one. It sends only 1 (the same) for both URLs, not 2 different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245809/discussion-between-joelcrypto-and-mronline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned from @Barmar in the comments above or in a PHP documentation [comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#100396) the solution is to use different realms.
I added an user-specific realm.

**working example:**

```
$auth = null;
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    $auth = login($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'], 'basic');
    if ($auth->getUser() != $theCorrectUser) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login for user '.$auth->getUserIdent().'"');
        header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8', true);
        http_response_code(403);
        echo 'wrong user';
        exit;
    }
}
if (!$auth) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login for user '.$auth->getUserIdent().'"');
    header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8', true);
    http_response_code(401);
    echo 'invalid user';
    exit;
}
// still there? -> user is logged in and correct
```